# Writing from a text file to SQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, text, python-idle

Hey I was just wondering if anyone would be able to help with writing the contents of a series of text files (e.g. activities.txt, sports.txt) (each has has a number, a tab, and a value (e.g. 90   Badminton) in each row). I have already initialised the database connection and have the table in SQL made ready to go.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Give examples of the input and output you want. Not just useful for us in helping, that's useful to you in designing a solution yourself.

Comment: I need to input the rows from the text files and output each piece of data to a specific column in the SQL table. 

For example, the table headers would be PersonId | Category | Type and the values would be 1 | Sports | Soccer.

I'd get this data from the text files
e.g. sports.txt

"1   Soccer
 2   Badminton
 3   Football"

etc

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly then the following snippet should get you started.  I'm going to assume you already have access to a cursor...

```
category = "Sports"
with open("sports.txt", "r") as sports:
    lines = sports.readlines()

for line in lines:
    # Split the line on whitespace
    data = line.split()
    number = data[0]
    value = data[1]

    # Put this through to SQL using an INSERT statement...
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO tablename (person_id, category, type)
                   VALUES(%s, %s, %s)""", (number, category, value))
```

Comment: You'll want to make sure you handle the case where `number`, `category` and `value` have single quotes in them.

Comment: I was almost ready to upvote until I saw the unescaped strings going into the SQL.  If one of the categories is "Bobby Tables' favorite strings" then you're going to have a problem...

Comment: The others are correct.  I meant to make use of DB-API's parameter substitution.  My post now reflects that...